# uninitialized constant Rack::MiniProfiler on staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, staging, rack-mini-profiler

I must to enable rack-mini-profiler for dev and production. In ApplicationController I have:

```
before_filter :miniprofiler

def miniprofiler
  Rack::MiniProfiler.authorize_request #if current_user.admin?
end
```

In config/initializers/rack_profiler.rb

```
if Rails.env == 'development'
  require 'rack-mini-profiler'

  Rack::MiniProfilerRails.initialize!(Rails.application)
end
```

In dev environment all works fine, but when i push to staging on Heroku, server falls with the

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Rack::MiniProfiler)
```

in this line

```
Rack::MiniProfiler.authorize_request #if current_user.admin?
```

I tried add

```
reqire 'rack-mini-profiler' to ApplicationController
```

but then I cann't even push it to staging with

```
Push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app
```

What i am missing?

Answer (score 3):

If the `rack-mini-profiler` gem is in the `:development` group in your Gemfile, then it is simply not installed on your staging server.

Answer (score 1):

Hi NOTE: Be sure to require the **rack_mini_profiler** gem below the **pg** and **mysql** gems in your Gemfile. rack_mini_profiler will identify these gems if they are loaded to insert instrumentation

And you don't really need the require line this method

```
if Rails.env == 'development'
 require 'rack-mini-profiler' //THIS LINE
 Rack::MiniProfilerRails.initialize!(Rails.application)
end
```